# что будет если вызвать другой метод из метода помеченным Transactional

Tags: java, spring

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.

Например, есть методы

```
@Transactional
public void methodA(){
   ...
   methodB();
   ...
}


public void methodB(){
   ...
}
```

Как поведет себя транзакция в данном случае.

Если подумать логически, то `methodB` тоже должен быть частью транзакции, так как он был вызван в рамках `methodА`, который помечен этой аннотацией. Ведь когда мы из сервиса обращаемся к ДАО слою, транзакция у нас идёт...

И, вдогонку вот такой вариант

```
@Transactional
public void methodA(){
   ...
   methodB();
   ...
}

@Transactional
public void methodB(){
   ...
}
```

Что будет в этой ситуации. Создастся новая транзакция?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222600/transactional-method-calling-another-method-without-transactional-anotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут, во-первых, надо уточнять о каких транзакциях идёт речь. Если мы говорим о БД, то оба варианта, в том виде, в котором они представлены, будут работать одинаково, в пределах одной транзакции.